# Cannot see older java version

Tags: java

There was already java8 installed on my computer. Now I have installed java6 because there is a project I have to maintain which was written with java6. I already set the `JAVA_HOME` to be C:\Program Files\Java\jre6. I restart the computer but when I launch on command line java -version then it is always 1.8.0_111. Then I changed the `JAVA_HOME` to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 but still get 1.8.0_111 !

So how to make the version 6 to be considered ?

Comment: I hope JAVA_HOME is there in the path as well.

Comment: Did you check other places, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `c:\java` ... search your drive... it's most probably still there

Comment: @vikingsteve, that doesn't matter as long as you have set a different version the the path right?

Comment: Try using: `setx JAVA_HOME <correctPath>`

Comment: In windows see in `control panel -> java` there also you can change the java version.

Comment: in control panel there are the two versions! So how to do ?

Comment: then enable the version you want to set. refer https://www.java.com/en/download/help/update_runtime_settings.xml